# Get related posts based on common tag?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `posts` table that has many-to-many relationship with `tags` table, connected using pivot table called `tagspivot`. I show a post using the following method :

```
public function showpost($titleslug) {
    $post = Post::where('titleslug','=',$titleslug)->first();
    return view('posts/show', compact('post', $post));
}
```

then I load the post tags in the `view` like :

```
@foreach($post->tags as $ptags)
  <li><a href="{{route('showtag', $ptags->titleslug)}}" class="button smallGrey">#{{$ptags->title}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

My question is, how to get a list of posts that has the same tags with the current showing post ? it doesn't have to be exact same tags, like the other post has one or two common tags. If possible the list is sorted by the post that has most common tags with the current showing post.

That's all, sorry for my bad English

Posts table :

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->string('titleslug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Tags table :

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('titleslug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Tagspivot table :

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('tagspivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Create tabel tagspivot
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('tag_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            // Set FK tagspivot --- posts
            $table->foreign('post_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('posts')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');

            // Set FK tagspivot --- tags
            $table->foreign('tag_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('tags')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Relationship in Post model :

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'tagspivot', 'post_id', 'tag_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Relationship in Tag model :

```
public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'tagspivot', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
```

Comment: So in showtag route you just want to load all posts that has that same tag, regardless of the other tags they have am I getting this right?

Comment: No, I mean like querying a list of posts that shares common tags with current showing post to get the most related posts. The `showtag` route is just showing a list of posts that belongs to a tag @OmarTarek

Comment: I think you should look at the Laravel documentation, the contains and whereIn method, I hope this helps a bit.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: Please, show your DB structure and current relations

Comment: Updated my question with DB structure @OdinThunder

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all post by current $titleslug you need use **whereHas** method:

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($titleslug) {
        $query->where('slug', $titleslug);
    })->get();
```

This code will work in case if you write your relations properly. For more information about whereHas and other helpfull relations methods watch this:

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Hope it help you to find right solution :)